# Is there a way to update web2py database table without locking the database?

Tags: python, web2py

I have an hourly process that updates one of my database tables - but when this is processing it presents errors due to the database being locked:

```
OperationalError: database is locked
```

Is there a way I can update the databases in web2py without them locking - or is there some other workaround I can take here?

Comment: It is probably your hourly process which is explicitly locking the database during the entire process. Maybe that is not necessary?

Comment: Ah interesting. I do need that to run if possible, however I could possibly run that through a separate project and transfer across in a quicker fashion at lower frequency

Comment: I meant maybe the locking is not necessary in your script. Some programmers include a lock just to be sure. Do you have access to the hourly script? And which database are you using? MySQL?

Comment: Yeah I do have access, I haven't explicitly put a lock on anything that I know of. I believe it's a SQLite DB which may be the limiting issue?

Comment: I don't know SQLite very well, but I read that it is transaction safe, so it should not need much locking. Unless you are doing large updates, such as replacing the entire table, I really don't see a motive for noticeable delays. Check if the update script uses row or table locking. Also, maybe the update policy should be revisited - may do incremental updates?